# Using member of base class before initialization

Tags: c++, inheritance, compiler-errors, initialization, warnings

In code below I am using `x` member of base class `A` to invoke `A` constructor, but the variable is not initialized, since there were no other `A` constructors invoked yet.

Why this code does not issue any error, or warning at least? Is there a way to make compiler complain about it?

```
struct A {
    int x;
    int y;

    A(int x, int y) : x{x}, y{y} {}
};

struct B : A {
    B() : A{1, x} {}
};
```

Comment: [Clang](https://wandbox.org/permlink/QAzKxRTvWI3hncsE) gives a warning for it.

Comment: I suspect that the reason for this behavior is similar to why `int x = x;` is allowed, but I am not the expert in such things.

Comment: What compiler are you using? What flags are you providing when you build?

Comment: gcc 7.3 with `-Wall -Wpedantic`, I forgot to test clang, now I see that clang issues a warning. Also I see on godbolt that trunk gcc also issues that warning, but any available release of gcc does not issue a warning even with `-Wuninitialized`.

Comment: The compiler is not *required* to emit a warning when you break the language rules and write code with undefined behaviour (in most cases). It is *your responsibility* to simply not write such code.

Comment: @JesperJuhl Thank you for your warning, but I would rather like for compiler to issue it for me.